# Detect object deletion through pointer

Tags: java, pointers, arraylist

Please consider the following code:

```
ArrayClass<someClass> list = new ArrayList<someClass>();
//Consider this list has been filled somewhere else

someClass selectedObject = null;

public void userAction(float x, float y){
    selectedObject = findObject(x, y);
}

public someClass findObject(float x, float y){
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
       if( --objects match-- )
           return list.get(i);

    return null;
}
```

The problem is that I'm using that selectedObject somewhere else, and I need to know that the object to which it points still exists. I've noticed that when the object in the list to which selectObject points is removed, the selectedObjects keeps the properties from the object it used to point to (which doesn't exist any more). I need selectedObject to point to null once the object is removed from the list. How can I achieve this?

EDIT1: To clarify, the posted code works, that is not the issue. The problem is that the pointer selectedObject is not updated when the object it points to in the list, is deleted. One more thing, I do not have access to the method that deletes objects from the list.

Comment: I don't see any problems with your code - it's just a matter of your logic. Where are you saying to set the object to null? What you are describing is both valid and achievable, but without seeing how you're currently doing it I can't tell you if you're doing it wrong.

Comment: You need to encapsulate the removal of the object and the keeping of selectedObject into one class. The method the removes the object from the list also needs to check whether it is the currently selected object, and set the field `selectedObject` to null if this is the case.

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve this if you make selectedObject a weak reference:

```
WeakReference<someClass> selectedObject = null;
```

assignment:

```
selectedObject = new WeakReference<someClass>(findObject(x, y));
```

query:

```
someClass v = selectedObject.get();
```

selectedObject get() method will return null if the item is removed from the list (and is not referenced by any other "pointer")

Comment: This will only work if garbage collector removed the actual object (reffered by WeakReference) from the heap. When the instance is removed from the list but still remains on the heap this will not work, so this is not solution in my opinion.

Comment: like I mentioned in the answer - this will work fine if the removed item is not referenced by any other variable. modern garbage collectors are pretty fast to clear young generation of heap. in any case, this is the best solution offered by Java. any other solution would have to be on the application level. you could save a reference to the list AND the selected object and then query the list if the selected object is still in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you put an object in a `List`, the `JVM` will keep one object and two references, so, if you need to be sure `selectedObject` is null, just assign `null` to it when found:

```
public someClass findObject(float x, float y){
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
       if( --objects match-- ) {
           selectedObject = null;
           return list.get(i);
       }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Think about this: in your code you will never erase all ALL references to the object since you need at least one to return it....

Comment: This way you need to call findObject each time. OP wants to call findObject() once and do not call it again, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper class which will inspect the list each time you want to access the instance:

```
class WrapperClass {

    private final List<SomeClass> list;
    private final float x;
    private final float y;


    WrapperClass(List<SomeClass> list, float x, float y) {
        this.list = list;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    SomeClass get() {
        return findObject();
    }

    private SomeClass findObject(){
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
            if( object_match(x, y) {
                return list.get(i);
            }

        return null;
    }

}
```

And than you call it:

```
   WrapperClass wp = new WrapperClass(list, 1, 2);
   System.out.println(wp.get()); // returns instance contained in the list

   list.clear();

   System.out.println(wp.get()); // returns null
```

Comment: This way you need to call findObject each time. OP wants to call findObject() once and do not call it again, I guess.

Comment: @sharonbn at least call to findObject() works in a background, but I agree that this solution is far from beeing perfect